# Simple CSS admin pagination

Tags: admin, admin-menu, admin-css

First of all thanks for your time :).

I have a dropdown menu option for the admin menu..but the pages still render at the menu edge.
[image]

Any css trick to position pages correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you achieve what you show in that picture? Pictures, by the way, are not worth a thousand words, code is.

Comment: First of all, this is not a wordpress specific question(It is a CSS issue). Anyway, you tried already *float:left*? Btw, showing specific code for that part would also be nice. Else we all have to guess what it can be.

Comment: @Charles : it looks to me like the standard left hand menu has been removed. How that was done could be relevant and may mean this is more than just CSS.

Comment: well there is a lot of code there.. using multiple files..but what i'm looking more specific are the syntaxes such as this #wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-site-name a.ab-item {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;       
    text-overflow: ellipsis;    
    float:right;              
}